# Condition for the sum of two fractions to be irreducible

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{e}{f}$ be two rationals where all parameters are positive integers and are in their lowest terms. Let $\gcd(b,f) = g$ so that $b = gB$, $f = gF$ and $\gcd(B,F) = 1$. As an intermediate step in one of the problems I am solving, I am interested in the following.

> **Weak Claim**: If $af+eb$ is square-free then $\gcd(aF+eB, gFB) = 1$.
>
> **Strong Claim**: If $ \min (\gcd(g,\frac{b}{g}),\gcd(g,\frac{f}{g})) > 1$
> then $\gcd(aF+eB, gFB) = 1$.

**Questions**

1. Are these condition correct? My derivation is given below.
2. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions?

**My solution**

Let $\gcd(b,f) = g$ so that $b = gB$, $f = gF$ and $\gcd(B,F) = 1$. After eleminating $g$ from the numerator and the denominator, we get

$$
\frac{1}{g}\Big(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{e}{f}\Big) = \frac{aF + eB}{gBF}
$$

We want to know if $\gcd(aF + eB, gBF) > 1$. Let us look at the different possibilities.

**Case 1**: $aF + eB$ and $B$ have a common factor. In this case since $B|eB$ hence we must have $\gcd(B,aF) > 1$. But by $\gcd(B,F) = 1$ hence we must have $\gcd(B,a) > 1$ which is impossible since $\frac{a}{b}$ is in its lowest terms. Hence this case is invalid.

**Case 2**: $aF + eB$ and $F$ have a common factor. In this case since $F|aF$ hence we must have $\gcd(F,eB) > 1$. But $\gcd(B,F) = 1$ hence we must have $\gcd(F,eB) > 1$ which is impossible since $\frac{e}{f}$ is in its lowest terms. Hence this case is also invalid.

**Case 3**: $aF + eB$ and $g$ have a common factor. Clearly $\gcd(g,a) = \gcd(g,e) = 1$  otherwise the fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{e}{f}$ will not be in their lowest terms. Also both $\gcd(g,B)$ and $\gcd(g,F)$ cannot be simultaneously $> 1$ otherwise $\gcd(b,f) > g$. Now

$$
\gcd(g, aF + eB) > 1 \implies \gcd(g^2, agF + egB) = \gcd(g^2, af + eb) > 1
$$

Hence $af+eb$ cannot be square free. This proves the weak claim.

We have two sub-cases:

**Subcase 3.1** $aF + eB$ and $g$ have a common factor and $\gcd(g,F) > 1$. In this case since $g$ has a common factor with both $F$ and $aF + eB$ it must have a common factor with $eB$ which is impossible. Hence this case is invalid.

**Subcase 3.2** $aF + eB$ and $g$ have a common factor and $\gcd(g,B) > 1$. In this case since $g$ has a common factor with both $B$ and $aF + eB$ it must have a common factor with $aF$ which is impossible. Hence this case is also invalid.

Hence the only possibility for $\gcd(aF + eB, gBF) > 1$ is when neither $F$ nor $B$ has a common factor with $g$ but $aF + eB$ always has a common factor with $g$.

Comment: I think $k$ and $d$ are irrelevant, and $u/v$ is in lowest terms if and only if $v/u$ is in lowest terms, so you are really asking for conditions on $a,b,e,f$ such that $(a/b)+(e/f)=(af+be)/(bf)$ is in lowest terms.

Comment: If $\gcd(b,f)=g>1$, then $(af+be)/(bf)$ can't possibly be in lowest terms, since $g$ will divide both numerator and denominator. I think the question you want to ask is whether, when $(af+be)/(bf)$ is reduced to lowest terms, the denominator is the least common multiple of $b$ and $f$.

Comment: This is not at all clear from the way the question is presented. In the 1st paragraph, all you mention is $(af+be)/(bf)$. Then in the blockquote just below that paragraph you claim conditions under which $(a/b)+(e/f)$ is in lowest terms, and then you ask whether it's correct. I was responding to that, without continuing to read the rest – the first part should stand on its own, without needing to read the rest to understand what you mean by it. Also, it takes some doing to get from your conclusion [continued, next comment]

Comment: [continued from previous comment] that is, the last line of your post, to the claim, which is stated in different notation. That is, your solution never gets tied up to the claim. The reasoning in your solution is correct, in my opinion.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to ask if a rational number (such as $\frac1g(\frac ab+\frac ef)$) is in lowest terms; one would need to ask whether a specific fraction, with specific numerator and denominator, is in lowest terms. What are the numerator and denominator of $\frac1g(\frac ab+\frac ef)$?

Comment: @GregMartin I have re-worded in terms of GCD which should make it meaningful.

Comment: Version 23 of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weak claim is correct but the strong claim is not. Here are streamlined arguments to that effect. We repeatedly use these facts (all variables are integers):

- If $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and $\gcd(x,z)=1$, then $\gcd(x,yz)=1$;
- $\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(x+wy,y)$.

Now note that:

- $\gcd(F,B)=1$ by construction, and $\gcd(F,e)=1$ follows from $\gcd(f,e)=1$ since $F\mid f$. Therefore $\gcd(F,eB)=1$, which implies that $\gcd(F,aF+eB)=1$.
- Similarly, $\gcd(B,F)=1$ by construction, and $\gcd(B,a)=1$ follows from $\gcd(b,a)=1$ since $B\mid b$. Therefore $\gcd(B,aF)=1$, which implies that $\gcd(B,aF+eB)=1$.

It follows that $\gcd(aF+eB,BF)=1$ and hence that $\gcd(aF+eB,gBF)=\gcd(aF+eB,g)$.

Suppose that $af+eb$ is squarefree. Setting $h=\gcd(aF+eB,g)$, we have $h\mid(aF+eB)$ and $h\mid g$ by definition, and therefore $h^2\mid(aF+eB)g = (af+eb)$; since $af+eb$ is squarefree, we must have $h=1$, proving the weak claim.

A counterexample to the strong claim is
$$
\frac ab=\frac5{12\times29}, \quad \frac ef=\frac7{18\times29},
$$
for which $g=6$ and $B=2$ and $F=3$, and $\min (\gcd(g,\frac{b}{g}),\gcd(g,\frac{f}{g})) = \min (2,3) = 2 > 1$, but $\gcd(aF+eB, gFB) = 29$.

In general, I don't know that there's going to be any simpler necessary and sufficient condition than $\gcd(aF+eB,g)=1$ itself, as the above example illustrates.